# How to add an SSD full of data into another machine

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, backup, ssd

Before I have an SSD and the SSD is used in one machine and installed with Ubuntu 16.04.
Now I unload it for that machine, and I wonder I can use it or access the data in that SSD upon another machine.

I have Lenevo M4000e-17, a laptop ThinkPad T430, and a laptop Lenovo G80.

Before I try to backup the system when SSD installed on the previous machine, but it is too slow and it is said that the system backup will go wrong when restoring.

So my question is how to backup a Ubuntu system and can be restored on another machine like Mac Time Machine, or some similar effect.

Anyone knows that?

Comment: You can put the SSD into an external USB drive enclosure, plug it into any machine and access the files directly.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Since I installed the operation system on the SSD, can I use the SSD directly and use the SSD's intalled operation system and do not need to install a new operation system?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix If putting the SSD into an external USB drive enclosure, how can I connect the SSD to the laptop or the desktop?

Comment: You plug the USB cable between the external drive enclosure and the laptop or desktop. It's instantly recognized and mounted.